# Flask-Caching not connecting to redis cluster in disabled cluster mode (aws hosted)

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster, redis-py, flask-caching

I am using the flask-caching library to use caching in my flask app. I am following the docs here: https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redisclustercache

When trying the connection on a cluster-enabled-mode cluster locally it works, however the app is stuck like this:
[image]

When I try to connect it to a hosted cluster in elasticache (disabled-cluster-mode) - I am using --tls auth.

Here is how the config looks like:

```
cache.init_app(
        app,
        config={
            "CACHE_TYPE": "RedisClusterCache",
            "CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD": config.REDIS_PASSWORD,
            "CACHE_REDIS_CLUSTER": "host:port", # aws-hosted cluster
            "CACHE_REDIS_DB": 0, # use the db=0
            "BUILD_TlS": "yes",
            "CACHE_OPTIONS": { # Even tried passing the password as extra option
                "-a":config.REDIS_PASSWORD,
            }
        },
    )
```

Comment: Seems like using redis cluster in no-cluster mode requires cache_type to be "RedisCache" - and used a redis connection url to connect.

Answer (score 1):

For cluster mode disabled, you want to set `CACHE_TYPE` to `RedisCache` instead of `RedisClusterCache`.

When you set `RedisClusterCache` the client attempts to discover the nodes in the cluster and it fails as the `CLUSTER NODES` [command](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes/) is not available. You should see an error similar to `Cluster mode is not enabled on this node`.